# In what Javascript engines does Function.prototype.toString not return the source code of that function?

Tags: javascript, interpreter

*EDIT: To be explicit, I am not looking for advice or opinions on the qualitative merit of the various issues implied by the functionality in question — neither am I looking for a reliable solution to a practical problem; I am simply looking for technical, verifiable answers to the question in the title. I have appended the question with a list of non-conforming browsers.*

Using a function's `.toString` method will typically [render the source code for that function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString). The problem is that this behaviour [isn't specified](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8) — the spec refrains from making any commitment as to what the behaviour should be when applied to functions. Chrome's console will even tell you (when you pass anything other than a function to `Function.toString.call`), that *Function.prototype.toString is not generic*

[This blog post](http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2013/05/multi-line-strings-in-javascript-and.html) suggests this can be used as a method to produce a readable syntax for multi-line strings (by storing the string as a multi-line comment in the body of [a no-op function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP)). The author suggests this usage in the context of writing [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) applications with the clause that this behaviour is only reliable because Node.js runs in a controlled environment. But in Javascript's native web, anything can come along and interpret it, and we shouldn't rely on unspecified behaviour.

In practice though, [I've set up a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/WPPYf/) which renders a select box whose contents are determined by a large multi-line string to test the code, and every browser on my workstation (Chrome 27, Firefox 21, Opera 12, Safari 5, Internet Explorer 8) executes as intended.

#### What current Javascript engines *don't* behave as follows?

Given that:

```
function uncomment(fn){
  return fn.toString().split(/\/\*\n|\n\*\//g).slice(1,-1).join();
}
```

The following:

```
uncomment(function(){/*
erg
arg
*/});
```

Should output:

```
erg
arg
```

#### List of non-conforming browsers:

- Firefox 16
- …

Comment: I think it is (or was) primarily on mobile browsers that it doesn't/didn't return the source. Also note that the source returned varies from implementation to implementation (re comments and whitespace).

Comment: And what if a browser engine comes out tomorrow that does not do this? It is a very fragile fundament to build upon.

Comment: Side note: There's no need for a `;` after a function *declaration*.

Comment: @bažmegakapa the second paragraph expresses this concern pretty explicitly: *But in Javascript's native web, anything can come along and interpret it, and we shouldn't rely on unspecified behaviour.* The question is: *which* (if any) browser engines don't do this.

Comment: @Barney Fine, but it renders the question pretty pointless. Any browser engine that does it today can decide to do it any other way tomorrow.

Comment: @bažmegakapa, nothing is a timeless absolute truth. That shouldn't detain us from questioning things as they are today. We can always update tomorrow.

Comment: @bažmegakapa the world of front-end changes continuously, new browsers fix some old bugs, break certain old bug fixes — but we manage! StackOverflow makes it that bit easier.

Comment: I tested this with FireFox 16...didn't work! Though it did work with Chrome. I find this very interesting as I've never thought of comments as having any bearing on an application aside from purely for descriptive purposes. I will continue with further testing, although, I think that building anything maintainable and stable in this fashion should be avoided as not all engines will process this information as intended.

Comment: @Barney I laid out the argument below and gave a nonconformant example (Firefox 16).  If that is not satisfactory, I suggest you download older browsers and try them out.  No one has tested it on all browsers (at least, based on my cursory search)

Comment: @Nirk sorry if my edits made it look like your answer wasn't appreciated — the intention had more to do with stemming comments here akin to "you shouldn't rely on this in production because it's non-standard".

Comment: @Barney i didn't mean to imply any frustration, but I think, based on what you said, the only way to answer your question is to brute force (which is what i essentially said in the first paragraph of my response).  The best way to approach this TBH is to decide what browsers you want to support (how far you want to go back) and then try everything.  Windows 7 has an XP mode so you can quickly fire up IE6/7/8 if you want to test those.

Comment: @Nirk Yes, I intend to do this at some point next weekend. As T.J. Crowder mentioned in the first comment though, mobile is the big grey area for this — which is really what I'm hoping to turn up here. As you say, old IEs are ripe for exploration because culturally, people tend to get locked in to them. The best thing I hope to dredge up from this question is the 'unknown unknowns' I wouldn't know about without someone happening to use rarer and hardware/OS-specific browsers I don't have access to.

Comment: @Barney The question you should then ask is whether those rarer browsers (outside of ios safari and android chrome) have enough potential users to care about those browsers.

Comment: @Barney kangax wrote about this 4 years ago: http://perfectionkills.com/those-tricky-functions/ (not really modern, but it drives home the point)

Comment: @Nirk Kangax — always 100 steps ahead of the rest of us… Thanks for the link!

Comment: @Nirk: There's an update: http://perfectionkills.com/state-of-function-decompilation-in-javascript/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What current Javascript engines don't behave this way?

Your question isn't really well-defined, given that you haven't defined "popular".  Is IE6 popular?  IE5?  IE4?  Netscape Navigator?  Lynx?  The only way to properly answer your question is to enumerate which browsers you wish to support and check them.  Unfortunately kangax's table http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/# doesn't test Function.prototype.toString

> Chrome's console will even tell you (when you pass anything other than a function o Function.toString.call), that Function.prototype.toString is not generic

mandated in the spec

> the spec refrains from making any commitment as to what the behaviour should be when applied to functions

The required behavior is specified in ECMA-262 version 1 (from 1997, http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%201st%20edition,%20June%201997.pdf)  You have to chase it down:

- http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.24 "function ... member of the Object type that is an instance of the standard built-in Function constructor and that may be invoked as a subroutine"

From that, we deduce that functions are objects.

- http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8 "Let primValue be ToPrimitive(input argument, hint String)."

So now what is ToPrimitive?

- http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.1 " The default value of an object is retrieved by calling the [[DefaultValue]] internal method of the object, passing the optional hint PreferredType. "

So we need to know what DefaultValue does

- http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.8 (lots of words that basically say if the thing has a toString method, then call it)

Now we just need to find where Function.prototype.toString is described:

- http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.2 "An implementation-dependent representation of the function is returned. This representation has the syntax of a FunctionDeclaration.  Note in particular that the use and placement of white space, line terminators, and semicolons within the representation String is implementation-dependent."

So you are guaranteed that you get a proper javascript representation (not some IL gobbledegook) but not necessarily with the comments.  For example, the technique breaks in Firefox 16 (but then you have to ask if it is current).

Comment: I edited the question to avoid the subjective 'popular', but I see your point — arguably the question is not appropriate to SO because there is no possible full answer, and you're fairly explicit as to why this is the case. In a way I'm reticent of marking your answer as accepted because what I'd really want is people to offer partial answers like "look, Opera X doesn't do it either", but then that's kind of gaming the SO format. In fact, downloading as many browsers as I can find and testing them all *is* the solution to the problem. Thanks for your comprehensive analysis!

Comment: Is IE6 popular is a question that should have been easily answerable by anyone who was attempting to answer this question. Sure, we can be pedantic and make the wild assumption that the OPs target audience is enterprise/corp users stuck with IE6. However, even in the rare circumstances where that could be true in June 2013, this question was obviously more abstract and generic than that which would have been presented by anyone believing IE6 was popular with a non-trivial subset of users.

Answer (score 1):

So Kangax has returned to the subject matter (intrigued as he was by the fact that Angular uses this hack for core functionality in client-side code) and written up an analysis of the practice, and produced a test table for [the state of function decompilation in Javascript](http://perfectionkills.com/state-of-function-decompilation-in-javascript/).

The takeaway points are that:

- The technique is only remotely reliable for user-defined function declarations.
- Some old mobile browsers will still collapse functional code, allegedly for performance reasons.
- Other old browsers will reveal optimized code, something like what you might get out of Closure Compiler.
- Yet others will remove comments and alter whitespace.
- Internet Explorer will occasionally add comments and whitespace around the functions.
- The AngularJS team seem to think this technique is robust enough to include in their library without explicit caveat. They then tokenize (!) the code and re-evaluate it (!!).

For my purposes, this makes me reasonably confident I can do something relatively undemanding like detect whether a function has an uppercase name or not by parsing it as follows:

```
/function\s*[A-Z]/.test( fn )
```