# Function serializability in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm reading a book (*Secrets.of.the.JavaScript.Ninja*) which Proposing a syntax that is used to accomplish an inheritance scheme.

Which will allow me to do :

```
var Person = Object.subClass(
{
          init: function (isDancing)
          {
              this.dancing = isDancing;
          } 
});


var Ninja = Person.subClass(
{
    init: function ()
    {
        this._super(false);
    } 
});
```

And here is the implementation code :

```
/*1*/   (function ()
/*2*/   {
/*3*/       var initializing = false,
/*4*/           superPattern =
/*5*/               /xyz/.test(function ()   {   xyz; }) ? /\b_super\b/ : /.*/;
/*6*/     
/*7*/       Object.subClass = function (properties)
/*8*/       {
/*9*/           var _super = this.prototype;
/*10*/           initializing = true;
/*11*/           var proto = new this();
/*12*/           initializing = false;
/*13*/           for (var name in properties)
/*14*/           {
/*15*/               proto[name] = typeof properties[name] == "function" &&
/*16*/                   typeof _super[name] == "function" &&
/*17*/                   superPattern.test(properties[name]) ?
/*18*/                   (function (name, fn)
/*19*/               {
/*20*/                   return function ()
/*21*/                   {
/*22*/                       var tmp = this._super;
/*23*/                       this._super = _super[name];
/*24*/                       var ret = fn.apply(this, arguments);
/*25*/                       this._super = tmp;
/*26*/                       return ret;
/*27*/                   };
/*28*/               })(name, properties[name]) :
/*29*/                   properties[name];
/*30*/           }
/*31*/   
/*32*/           function Class()
/*33*/           {
/*34*/               // All construction is actually done in the init method
/*35*/               if (!initializing && this.init)
/*36*/   
/*37*/                   this.init.apply(this, arguments);
/*38*/           }
/*39*/           Class.prototype = proto;
/*40*/           Class.constructor = Class;
/*41*/           Class.subClass = arguments.callee;
/*42*/           return Class;
/*43*/       };
/*44*/   })();
```

My question is about line #5  :

I know that  : the `test()` method expects a string, which triggers the function’s  `toString()` method

But why didn't he use the simple toString method ?

```
function getStringFromFunction(fn)
{
  return fn.toString();      
}
```

What am I missing ? I'm pretty sure there is a reason for using this regex and not simple toString...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose he is concerned with this issue: http://my.opera.com/hallvors/blog/show.dml/1665828 since John Resig is explicitly called out by the author.

At the same time `Function.prototype.toString()` is part of the ECMAScript spec and according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16989196/782609) it's quite safe to use.

Comment: off-topic (a bit) Q :   but what if someone overrides `.toString()` ? I thought I should do `Object.prototype.toString.apply(function a(b){c;})` but it returns : `"[object Function]"` ( and i want it to return the string representation) . is there any way i can use the pure toString method ? ( without being afraid that `toString` was overridden) ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir - unfortunately I don't know any way to do this.

Comment: I found it : `Function.prototype.toString.apply(function a(b){c;})`

Comment: @RoyiNamir - aah, okay. I thought you want `Object.prototype.toString`  to work after it was overriden.