# Why toString is not a generic function in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

I was trying to do something like this.

```
 var myFunc = function() {}
 myFunc.prototype = new String();
 myFunc.prototype.replace = function() {return 'hii, Mr '+ this.toString();}       

 var oVal = new myFunc('Jyotirmay');
 oVal.replace();
```

**o/p :: Uncaught TypeError: String.prototype.toString is not generic(…)**

Why "function not generic" error comes actually in general?

As to be more clear, How can i pass my argument i.e Jyotirmay from inherited class to base class i.e string. So that i can get that value by calling any proper string function.

I don't want to get my passed value from my function by handling that variable in it. 
I want that to be handled by parent class. You can say super() in other languages.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937940/in-what-javascript-engines-does-function-prototype-tostring-not-return-the-sourc
Take a look at this answer. :)

Comment: @Gaurav, Go through that before asking this, because i am not getting my solution from that post. Anyway thanx :)

Comment: What is it you are actually asking? Help with your code or why is `toString` not generic?

Comment: @Xotic750  you can answer both.

Comment: Are you just trying to create your own prototypical object with its own methods or are you actually trying to create a subclass of `String` and override the `replace` method? It is not clear.

Comment: @Xotic750,  i am trying to override replace method of String by returning hii, Mr + whatever string that instance contain at that point of time when my overridden replace function will be called.

Comment: If you are just trying to override `String`s `replace` method, then just `String.prototype.replace = function () { ... };` no need to create a subclass of native `String`.

Comment: In simple word, i want to return current value hold by my instance to the function which i am overriding. Everytime for all functions, it gave not generic error. Tried with toLocaleString() as well

Comment: Your comment's have not made your intention any clearer. Can you explain what you believe you are achieving with this line of code `myFunc.prototype = new String();`?

Comment: By that line, i am inheriting from String.

Comment: And why do you want to subclass the `String` object? I thought you said `i am trying to override replace method of String`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear what exactly you are trying to achieve from your question and comments, but perhaps this is all you are trying to do?

```js
function myFunc(inputArg) {
    this.inputArg = inputArg;
}

myFunc.prototype = {
    replace: function () {
        return 'hii, Mr ' + this.inputArg;
    },
    
    toString: function () {
        return '' + this.inputArg;
    }
};

myFunc.prototype.valueOf = myFunc.prototype.toString;

function log(inputArg) {
    document.getElementById('out').appendChild(document.createTextNode(inputArg + '\n'));
}

var oVal = new myFunc('Jyotirmay');

log(oVal);
log(oVal.replace());
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

As to `Why is toString not generic`, this is because not all objects can be represented as a string by the same conversion method.

**Update based on your latest comment**

Native objects are notoriously difficult, if not impossible, to subclass in Javascript. There are a few hacks that will allow you partial success, but I would not recommend them and good luck across different environments.

Two (but not the only) such hacks are:

Stealing from an `iframe`

```js
function stealObject(objectName, myVariableName) {
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

    iframe.style.display = 'none';
    iframe.src = 'javascript:parent.' + myVariableName + ' = ' + objectName;
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    document.body.removeChild(iframe);

    return window[myVariableName];
}

function log(inputArg) {
    document.getElementById('out').appendChild(document.createTextNode(inputArg + '\n'));
}

try {
    stealObject('String', 'MyString');
    MyString.prototype.replace = function () {
        return 'hii, Mr ' + this;
    };


    var oVal = new MyString('Jyotirmay');

    log(oVal);
    log(oVal.toUpperCase());
    log(oVal.replace());
} catch (e) {
    log(e);
}
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Doesn't work in SO snippets because `SecurityError: Sandbox access violation:` but can see it on this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/jgybkbmd/). `typeof oVal` will return `object` and not `string` and `oVal instanceof String` will be `false`. `oVal.constructor === String` will return `false`.

Another hack

```js
function MyString() {
    this.str = '' + arguments[0];
};

with(MyString.prototype = new String()) {
    toString = valueOf = function () {
        return this.str;
    };
}

MyString.prototype.replace = function () {
    return 'hii, Mr ' + this;
};

function log(inputArg) {
    document.getElementById('out').appendChild(document.createTextNode(inputArg + '\n'));
}

var oVal = new MyString('Jyotirmay');

log(oVal);
log(oVal.toUpperCase());
log(oVal.replace());
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

The magic `length` property is broken in this one and you would need to call `oVal.toString().length` instead. `typeof oVal` will return `object` and not `string` but `oVal instanceof String` will be `true`. `oVal.constructor === String` will return `true`.

Comment: updated the question. Hope you will get a clear view now. I want string to handle my passed argument and not my own function. Like a super().  ??

Comment: I can't believe that you can execute arbitrary code in an iframe loaded from another domain, just by setting its src to "javascript:" ... this works in modern browsers??